# Lorentz transformation of covariant tensors

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

I want to derive the rule of the Lorentz Transformation of covariant vectors (tensors) from the transformation rule of the metric and contravariant vectors.
Starting out one can write the equation:
$$x'_\mu=g'_{\mu\nu} x'^\nu$$
Using the transformation rule of the Minkowski metric $g'_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}$ and the transformation rule for contravariant vectors: $x'^\nu=\Lambda^\nu_\alpha x^\alpha$
I arrive at $$x'_\mu=g_{\mu\nu} \Lambda^\nu_\alpha x^\alpha$$
I think I am very close. What I need to do is bring the Lorentz Transformation to the left side and then I should somehow be able to pull the index of the contravariant tensor down. But I am not sure how to do that, because the Lorentz Transformation is contracted with both indices.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's different ways to do this so I'll just pick one. As correctly commented the metric is invariant $g'_{\mu \nu}= \Lambda^{\alpha}{}_{\mu} \Lambda^{\beta}{}_{\nu}g_{\alpha \beta} = g_{\mu \nu}$.  Act on both sides with the inverse $(\Lambda^{-1})_{\alpha}{}^{\mu}$ to get $\Lambda^{\beta}{}_{\nu}g_{\alpha \beta} = (\Lambda^{-1})_{\alpha}{}^{\beta} \, g_{\beta \nu}$. Using this in your equation, and using the metric to lower the index on $x^{\alpha}$
$$
x'_{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu} \Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} g^{\alpha \beta} x_{\beta}=  (\Lambda^{-1})_{\mu}{}^{\nu} \, g_{\alpha \nu}g^{\alpha \beta} x_{\beta}
= (\Lambda^{-1})_{\mu}{}^{\nu}\, x_{\nu} \ .
$$